# How to ignore parents div center position

Tags: html, css

The div (page-wrap) is the page container, it has a width of 960px and its position is centered to the middle of the page. I want to have a child div that ignores this and has the width of the page.

```
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin:0 auto;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

I want this div to ignore the above

```
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <img src="logo.jpg" width="150px" height="75px">
    <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position: absolute;` only if there isn't any parent element with `position:relative`, otherwise there is no option to achieve this I guess.

```css
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /*added*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrap">
  <img src="logo.jpg" width="150px" height="75px">
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are 3 types of positions in CSS :

- static
- relative
- fixed
- absolute

In your case, you want to use any of them except *absolute*. Try and see what fits best for your needs.

[read this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Seems hack-ish, but it might work.

*Known % width* method.

https://jsfiddle.net/eulloa/5308kd5r/2/

```
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* addition */
  margin-left: -33.33%;
  margin-right: -33.33%;
}
```

Source. Includes alternatives.
https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/